# CSS design of Current Item (wordpress multi pages posts)

Tags: css, wordpress

so I have made some css for the multi paged posts in wordpress but can't figure out how to change background of the current page.
my css property for this is POSTPAGES, so I tried

---

.postpages:active and .postpages.active

---

.postpages:current and .postpages.current

---

but all didn't work...

Please help me figure this out.
thanks

--
edit: More Information
Refer to this link:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links

I am using this multiple page page system in my posts. So, If my posts has more than one pages, then it'll show number of Pages the post is split into.

Now, What I want is that when someone is at the first page of post then the page number's background should be something else. For this purpose, I need some CSS codes so that I can define different CSS properties for the **CURRENT** or **ACTIVE** page.

Comment: I think some more information will be needed for this question to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making any CSS selector more specific you can override any other style. In this case specifying "body" before a declaration will override all others, except inline styles.

```
body .postpages {
   ...
}
```